Can I typehint a php enum?
I want to refactor my codebase from MyCLabs Enums to PHP's native enum's. I'm already running into a few small issues:

How can I typehint that an argument or return type must be an enum?
How can I check if a value is an enum?

The best I can do with regards to typehinting is typehinting object.
The best I can do for checking if a value is an enum is with with a ReflectionClass, eg:
if (
    is_object($value)
    && (new ReflectionClass($value))->isEnum()
) {
    // it's an enum.
}

Without these simple checks, it feels like refactoring to native enums is a step backwards. Am I approaching it incorrectly?

Do you mean it can be any enum?
